# Error While Configuring Spring Security with Custom User and Password Encoder

Tags: spring-boot

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration {

    
    //InMemoryUserDetailsManager(UserDetails... users)
    
        
    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager createUserDetailsManager() {
        
        Function<String, String> passwordEncoder
                = input -> passwordEncoder().encode(input);
        
        UserDetails userDetails = User.builder()
                                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                                    .username("abc")
                                    .password("123")
                                    .roles("USER","ADMIN")
                                    .build();
        
        return InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

above configuration gives:

```
Error:The method InMemoryUserDetailsManager(UserDetails) is undefined for the type SpringSecurityConfiguration
Error:The method BCryptPasswordEncoder() is undefined for the type SpringSecurityConfiguration
```

Comment: You're missing `new` after both `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `new` keyword in the `return` statemnet

Try this

```
return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
```

and

```
return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
```

hope it will solve your issue.